# Key binding not functioning properly java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am writing a class that simply listens for key presses.  I am using it with JFrame, so I am using key binding.  The getWindow() method returns a JFrame window which has been already created and is working fine.  However, the key binding is either not working, or the action is not being called.

Any way, here is my code, keys.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class keys extends Thread{
        private JFrame window;

        public keys(){
                snake getInfo = new snake();
                window = getInfo.getWindow();
        }

        public void run(){
                System.out.println("keys us called");
                Action pressed = new AbstractAction(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                System.out.println("working");
                        }
                };
                JPanel content = (JPanel)window.getContentPane();
                content.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "pressed");
                content.getActionMap().put("pressed", pressed);
        }
}
```

Keys is running on a separate thread so that the program can continue.  I haven't been coding in java for very long, so I'm sorry if this is a ridiculous question.  I have never used key binding as well.  Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: First things first, in Java `class` names as **always** in `PascalCase` - `camelCase` is reserved for variables. No exceptions. No excuses.

Comment: Now, your actual issue, Swing is **not** multi-threaded. Any attempt to access Swing elements on any thread other than the EDT will result in random, unexpected and inexplicable behaviour.

Comment: Java has some good tutorials for these kinds of things, here is one for [how to write a key listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: @BoristheSpider So is there any way I can do this?

Comment: I see no reason for using another thread to begin with. Get rid of it. Further, you haven't shown us your `main` method - but your application should be started with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25804241/2071828). This ensures that all the code runs on the EDT.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you. I didn't fully understand the way that the binding worked, so I thought that it needed to be constantly running on another thread so the program could continue. It works fine now.