# How to acces values from within MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, vector, mouselistener

I am trying to update the value of the variable 'dest' with the mouse location whenever pressed. 
but whenever checking if the value has been updated (in the run method) i see that it has not been. where am i wrong?

```
public class Boid extends JPanel implements Runnable{   
    private Vector2D dest = new Vector2D(300,300);

    public Boid ()          
        addMouseListener (new MouseAdapter() {          
            public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e) {           
                Boid.this.dest = new Vector2D(e.getX(), e.getY());
                System.out.println("mouse "+Boid.this.squareX);
            }
        });
    }


    public void run(){                      
        System.out.println(dest);       
    }

    public void drawBoid(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine((int)pos.getX(), (int)pos.getY(), (int)dest.getX(), (int)dest.getY());
    }

}
```

(edited)
i am calling the run method in the following way. not sure this is the right way, i'm moving from processing so this is how i thought it may work...

```
public class GUI{
    private static Boid b = new Boid();
    private static Timer TT;    

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
            JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Boid GUI");
            mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainFrame.setResizable(false);
            mainFrame.setSize(640,480);
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
            contentPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,480)); 
            contentPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            mainFrame.add(contentPanel);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);  

            ActionListener updateDrawing = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                    
                    b.run();                       
                    b.drawBoid(contentPanel.getGraphics());

                }
            };

            TT = new Timer(50, updateDrawing);
            TT.start();
    }
}
```

also tried the following main, but seems like the boid.run method then only 'runs' once:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Boid GUI");
            mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainFrame.setResizable(false);
            mainFrame.setSize(640,480);
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
            contentPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,480)); 
            contentPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            mainFrame.add(contentPanel);
            setWindow(mainFrame);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);  

            b.run();
        }
        });
}
```

Comment: How are you calling these? Is it possible that `run` completes before the mouse click?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803428/how-to-load-a-java-gui-class-from-a-main-class). It will get your GUI on the EDT where it belongs. Are you trying to click the GUI before the `Timer` runs? You're only giving yourself 50ms to do that.

Comment: i've tried changing the timer to 500 but still wouldn't update. also tried to implement roughly what was in the question (frame>add penel>size>show) but the boid.run method then only runs once (see code above)

Comment: You shouldn't explicitly call the run method of a Runnable. Other than the answer below your overall way of that design isn't correct, you would place a Runnable in a Thread and start the Thread

Comment: that's now clearer. 'static Thread t = new Thread (new Boid());' ... 't.start()' ...what i still don't get is how do i constantly run this so that the drawing would continue updating?

Answer (score 0):

You whole design is incorrect. That is not how you do custom painting.

1. There is no need for the Timer.
2. You don't use getGraphics()

> I am trying to update the value of the variable 'dest' with the mouse location whenever pressed

Some painting basics:

1. You need to override the `paintComponent(...)` method of the panel to do some painting.
2. In your case you need some properties in your class to paint. So you would want variables like mouseX and mouseY. You then need a method like `setMouseLocation(x, y)` that allows you to change these variables.
3. When the mouse click happens you invoke the `setMouseLocation(...)` method of your panel with the new values and then you invoke `repaint()` on your panel.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the variable as 'public static' would make it accessible from anywhere in your project.