# Consistently make a button visible on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

My program complies and displays a blank frame. I have tried  multiple ways, but I am thinking this should work, I don't understand why  it doesn't?
The code is simple it just shows a blank box and a button that informs the user the action Listener is working.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Udemy {

  public Udemy() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setTitle("La's Frame");
    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    f.getContentPane().add(panel);

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Click me");
    panel.add(b1);
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("Action Listener is working");
      }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Udemy ud = new Udemy();
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't pack the frame

Comment: ..or start the GUI on the EDT. Or indent the code logically, but that won't contribute to whether it works reliably, just on how easy it is to read, and possibly how much help is offered. Also, don't set the frame visible until after all the components have been added, and `pack()` has been called as suggested by @cricket_007 ..

Comment: Call setVisible last after the ui is established or revalidate and repaint the container

Comment: You should do it like there: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25804241/5509049)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a Java GUI class from a main class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803428/how-to-load-a-java-gui-class-from-a-main-class)

Answer (score 1):

Here, I moved `f.setVisible(true);` to the bottom and everything works fine

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Udemy {

public Udemy(){
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setTitle("La's Frame");
f.setSize(400,400);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


JPanel panel = new JPanel();
f.getContentPane().add(panel);

JButton b1 = new JButton("Click me");
panel.add(b1);
f.setVisible(true);

b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     System.out.println("Action Listener is working");
     }
   });
 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
     Udemy ud = new Udemy();

      }
   }
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer as per code the button was not visible and now it is am i right?

Comment: The button was always visible, it just hadn't been rendered, Swing is lazy, it, generally, won't update the ui until you tell it, moving setVisible to the just delays the time when the ui should be displayed, so the ui must be laid out and painted at that point. You can trigger a layout pass by calling revalidate and a paint pass with repaint, typically you do this together