# Calling a Java GUI method from another class

Tags: java, swing

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm trying to call a GUI method from a different class into my main class but am having trouble, when running the program from the GUI class everything works fine but when I run the main class I get error messages in the console.

These are the errors I get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself
at java.awt.Container.checkAddToSelf(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at mathsQuiz3_1_1.MathsQuiz_3_1_1_Main$1.run(MathsQuiz_3_1_1_Main.java:16)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Maths_Quiz_3_1_1_GUI GUIObject = new Maths_Quiz_3_1_1_GUI();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            GUIObject.setDefaultCloseOperation(Maths_Quiz_3_1_1_GUI.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            GUIObject.getContentPane().add(GUIObject);
            GUIObject.pack();
            GUIObject.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Heres the GUI class

```
package mathsQuiz3_1_1;
```

`public class Maths_Quiz_3_1_1_GUI extends JFrame {`

```
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Maths_Quiz_3_1_1_GUI frame = new Maths_Quiz_3_1_1_GUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Maths_Quiz_3_1_1_GUI() {

    JPanel contentPane;
    JPanel pnlStartScreen = new JPanel();
    JPanel pnlAnswerScreen = new JPanel();
    JPanel pnlQuestionResult = new JPanel();
    JPanel pnlEndScreen = new JPanel();

    ButtonGroup btngrpQuestionType = new ButtonGroup();

    /**
     * JFrame
     */

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 1100, 700);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
```

I have removed the rest of the code which is just adding more elements to the jframe.

I have looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803428/how-to-load-a-java-gui-class-from-a-main-class) in which the user had a similar problem and tried implementing the solution gave there but am still having no luck. Any help that anyone could provide would be helpful as I'm new to programming and am not sure about how to use GUIs and calling methods.

Comment: [Please format your code blocks carefully](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Be sure to see your question in the preview section to see if it's correctly rendered before asking.

Comment: Why do you title this as "calling a gui method from another class"?   The exception you are getting doesn't seem to indicate there is a problem with finding classes or not finding methods.   It says a containers parent is getting added to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...

does the combination of

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **adding container's parent to itself**

and

```
 GUIObject.getContentPane().add(GUIObject);
```

ring a bell?

Comment: ok, so i changed this to "frame.getContentPane().add(GUIObject);" but am now getting the error of "adding a window to a container.

Comment: It seems that now you're adding a window to a container. (sorry for the pun). You should simplify your code and build a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'm almost expecting that such a simplification will make you find the issue yourself.