# Link GUI to Main Class

Tags: java, swing

I've created a java program and created the GUI for it. But I'm unable to link them together since this is my very first java program. my codes are as follows.

Main

```
public class FinalN {

    private static void setRoundedCorners(XSSFChart chart, boolean setVal) {
        if (chart.getCTChartSpace().getRoundedCorners() == null) chart.getCTChartSpace().addNewRoundedCorners();
        chart.getCTChartSpace().getRoundedCorners().setVal(setVal);
    }
    public static void main (String[]args) throws Exception {
        File src= new File("C:\\Users\\File.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream (src);

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet1= wb.getSheetAt(0);
// Continues
```

GUI

```
public class UserInterface {

    public class java {

    }

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
```

I've tried to get an idea from this post [How to load a Java GUI class from a main class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803428/how-to-load-a-java-gui-class-from-a-main-class) 
but I'm unable to complete the task. Please help

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by "link together".

Comment: I need to call UI class from the Main class. To run the UI with my main code together.

Comment: Have a look at [The Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) for a better idea of how GUIs work.

Comment: We cannot answer this question because we neither see your code nor know how you GUI should interact with your main program. So I vote to close this topic as `unclear what you're asking`.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to instantiate the GUI class in the FinalN class
and add the code inside the constructor of GUI.

Code for main() function:

```
public static void main (String[]args) throws Exception {
File src= new File("C:\\Users\\File.xlsx");
FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream (src);
UserInterface gui = new UserInterface();
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet1= wb.getSheetAt(0);
}
```

Code for Constructor to create a basic GUI using JFrame

```
public class UserInterface {
private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;
private JButton button;
public UserInterface() {
    frame = new JFrame("Name of the Frame");
    textField = new JTextField(20); //width of the textfield
    button = new JButton("Click"); //text on the button
    frame.add(textField); //adding the component to the frame, all components must be explicitly added like this
    frame.setVisible(true); //to make the frame visible
    frame.setSize(500,500); //width and height of frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //to make the frame close on pressing x button on the frame
}
```

This should help you create a basic frame GUI from your main method in the implementing class. Please ask if you need more clarification

Comment: If my example answers your question, I hope you can mark it as accpted @LSH94